# How to get notification to repeat daily

Tags: swift

When I call my notification function, it will trigger at the original time. However, I never get another notification after that. I noticed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335557/repeat-daily-local-notifications-in-ios-10-does-not-get-triggered-when-manually/43343667) was dealing with a similar issue. I changed my code to mimic the solution. I still didn't receive another notification.

Here is the code:

```
static func scheduleNotification(hour:Int, minutes:Int, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    notificationContent.title = "Hello "
    notificationContent.subtitle = "Now might be a good time for a check in"

    var dateInfo = DateComponents()
    dateInfo.hour = hour
    dateInfo.minute = minutes

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateInfo, repeats: true)
    print(trigger.nextTriggerDate()!)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: Notifications.notificationIdentifier, content: notificationContent, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
        if error != nil {
            print("\(error)")
            completion(false)
        } else {
            completion(true)
        }
    })
}
```

The intention is to have it trigger daily at 4:00pm.

```
        scheduleNotification(hour: 16, minutes:00, completion: {success in
            if success {
                print("Successfully scheduled notification")
            } else {
                print("Could not schedule notification")
            }
        })
```

I printed the result of the nextTriggerDate function to see if it would return the original trigger date or the date of the following day. In this case, the date is 4-18-2018.

The trigger that gets returned is

> 2018-04-18 23:00:00 +0000

I'm also not sure why the date returned adds 7 hours to my intended trigger time. The notification still fires at 4:00. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**short answer**

add

```
dateInfo.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
```

and it will work like expected.

**explanation**

I tried myself with hour 16 and minutes 0.

I got `14:00` as result. The reason is because I'm living in Germany and Germany (GMT+2, summer time) has at the moment +2 hours distance to UTC.

The defaults timezone of my device is GMT+2. I add 16 hours and `DateComponent` handle this date as GMT+2 but converts that value to UTC. 
So 16 (input) - 2 (GMT) = 14 UTC.

I'm always try to work with UTC dates... everything else causes me a headache.